# Why is a successful search in a chained hash table have a time complexity of Θ(1+(n/m)) on average?

Tags: algorithm, search, hashtable, time-complexity, big-o

I get why an unsuccessful search in a chained hash table has a time complexity of Θ(1+(n/m)) on average, because the expected number of elements examined in an unsuccessful search is (n/m), and the total time required (including the time for computing hashFunction(key)) is Θ(1+(n/m)). But why is it the same for a successful search?

Comment: are you asking about the `1`? the answer is right in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to "Algorithms: Design and Analysis" by Cormen et al. expected number of key comparisons during successful search in a hash table with separate chaining collision resolution is 1 + α/2 - α/2n [where α=n/m]. Intuitive explaination: since this is a successful search, we check at least one key (we search for it), and a half of the rest keys in a chain.

Time complexity: Θ(1 + 1 + α/2 - α/2n) = Θ(1 + α), by definition of big-theta notation.

Answer (score 2):

**For a Successful search**

NOTATION: α= n/m = load factor

**A) MATHEMATICAL PROOF**

1)Assume that a new element is inserted at the end of the linked list

2)Upon insertion of the i-th element, the expected length of the list is (i-1)/m

3)In case of a successful search, the expected number of elements examined is 1 more that the number of elements examined when the sought-for element was inserted!

*The expected number of elements examined is thus*

[Calculation of expected time for successful search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmsmo.png)

Now add '1' to signify the time for computing the hash function

We get,

[Final Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA1Za.png)

**B)INTUITION**
For successful search you will compute hash function O(1) and traverse through half of the keys in the chain on average

Comment: In this image "http://i.stack.imgur.com/zmsmo.png" How can 1 Can be put out of summation .?

Answer (score 2):

The total time for a successful and unsuccessful search in absolute terms is not equal. They are equal only when we talk of asymptotic notations.

Total time for a successful search would be equal to 1 + number of elements in the chained list before the key required.
This problem then boils down to find the average number of elements which will be added after a particular key is added in the chained list.

Suppose key k1 is to be searched. Initially in the preparation of the table , k1 is added at the head of T[h(k1)].
Let the number of elements after the addition of element with key k1 be x. Thus we still have (n-x ) elements to be added in the table.

As this x value could be 1 to n  ( as the key k1 will always be in the table) so we sum (n-x) from 1 to n and multiply it by the probability of going in the same index where key k1 is added. P(h(any key) = 1/m

Thus average comes out to be :
 1 + {(1/n) (Summation (1/m)(n-x))}

The lower limit and upper limit of x will be 1 and n respectively.
This comes out to be Theta(1 + n/m).

Comment: You gave just a brilliant explanation! Thank You so much! The only thing I did not get is why did you divide the result of summation by `1/n`?

Answer (score 0):

Successful search in a chained has a time complexity O(1 + n/m) not Θ(1+(n/m) because if you find your element you can stop. There is no need to look at the rest of elements.